# Using ST_Transform when inserting new row?

Tags: postgis

I have written a script which reads a CSV file with lat/lon coordinates in WGS84 and inserts them into a table in PostGIS.

What I want to do now is to change the insert query in order to make a transformation of the coordinates from WGS84 to another reference system.
My qyestion is if something like this is possible while inserting the data.

I was trying something like this but doesn't work:

```
   INSERT INTO imgRural(geom) VALUES (ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(23.771111111111 38.013888888889)', 2100)),2100) RETURNING imgId;
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You need to set the SRID to 4326 before you can transform it. Something like, INSERT INTO imgRural(geom) VALUES (ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(23.771111111111 38.013888888889)', 4326), 2100)) RETURNING imgId;

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I followed your suggestion and with some small modification in worked.INSERT INTO imgRural(geom) VALUES (ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(23.771111111111 38.013888888889)',4326),2100)) RETURNING imgId;

Comment: Oh, yes, forgot the comma, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `John Barca` said in his comment: I neglected to set the SRID before the transformation. This worked fine:

```
   INSERT INTO imgRural(geom) VALUES (ST_Transform
   (ST_GeomFromText('POINT(23.771111111111 38.013888888889)',4326),2100)) 
   RETURNING imgId;
```